# Como "saltar" bucles con el debugger, intelliJ, Java

Tags: java

Pues mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que un bucle for se ejecute entero sin tener que estar pulsando la tecla F7 todo el rato. Lo quiero para un for que me imprime una matriz que va cambiando, y claro, si voy con el F7 me tiro tres años.

Es decir, no se como hacer que el for dentro de una sentencia que estoy pasando con el debugger se haga como si no lo estuviera pasando con el debugger, no se si me explico.

He buscado respuesta por los foros y no he encontrado(que no digo que no esté).

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda.
Un saludo
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es poner un **break** en la llave donde termina el **for** y para visualizar el resultado puedes poner un

```
 System.out.println("Resultado matriz: " + nombreVariable);
```

con eso puedes ver mas rapido el resultado.